# Как узнать value выбранного option из списка select

Tags: javascript, html, select

```html
<select size="1" multiple name="numbers[]" id="select">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
```

В JS самое короткое было (перед этим нашли select):

```
alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
```

Выдаёт ошибку об отсутствии `value`.
Задача: вывести значение выбранного option.

Answer (score 2):

`option` не нужно, обращайтесь сразу к `select`:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#select');

console.log(element.value)

element.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const element = document.querySelector('#select');
  alert(element.value)
});
```

```css
#select {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
 
    line-height: 40px;
    
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<select size="1" multiple name="numbers[]" id="select">
    <option value="0">ноль</option>
    <option value="1" selected>один</option>
    <option value="2">два</option>
    <option value="3">три</option>
    <option value="4">четыре</option>
    <option value="5">пять</option>
    <option value="6">шесть</option>
    <option value="7">семь</option>
    <option value="8">восемь</option>
</select>
```